# Android components pallete

Tags: android, netbeans, components, pallet

I configured Android 4.0 in my netbeans ide (verion 7.1.1). I am able to create a Android project but am unable to see any components pallete in the tools section to drag and drop to the layout main xml ?
Unfortunately right clicking on the xml code doesnt give me an option "Open on graphical editor".

Can anyone please help on this ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no UI designer for Android layouts in NBAndroid and I am not aware of any other Android development support for NetBeans. You can try layout preview http://www.nbandroid.org/2012/11/early-version-of-preview-functionality.html to see how your project will render.

Comment: Thanks. I couldnt find the layout preview in windows -> output - >. I could only find ADB log there. I guess I need to switch to eclipse to get all the features for android development.